# How do I get a Windows folder containing a lot of large .EXE files to resolve quicker?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, file-management

When I have a folder on Windows (any version from 7 to 8.1) that contains a number of large .EXE files such as installer files like Firefox Setup and CCleaner (usually about 10-100mb), it lags the session, the fan becomes very noisy and it takes about 1 or 2 minutes for everything to be resolved on a Core 2 Duo with 4GB RAM.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: additional processing power and memory helps.

Comment: Having indexing turned on for your drive should help. If it is already  turned on, then it might be just a matter of your processing power and memory, as @Ramhound says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your virus scanner is scanning all of them. You may want to change the scanner that you use, or disable the Active Scan component of it.

Comment: yes, MSE/Defender slows the Explorer dramatically down. I had the same issue.